# AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'epochs_per_eval'

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, namespaces

I'm trying to run tensorflow wide_deep training model using latest docker model. I have mounted the official model to the docker image

`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 --mount type=bind,src="$(pwd)",target=/notebooks/model tensorflow/tensorflow`

As mentioned in the doc, I have added the model directory to the python path.

Then I downloaded the dataset using `python download_data.py`

After down, when I run `python wide_deep.py` it throws this error

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': device_count {
  key: "GPU"
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_task_type': 'worker', '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_is_chief': True, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7f69d55f0510>, '_evaluation_master': '', '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_service': None, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_master': '', '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_task_id': 0, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_model_dir': '/tmp/census_model', '_save_summary_steps': 100}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wide_deep.py", line 230, in <module>
    main(argv=sys.argv)
  File "wide_deep.py", line 199, in main
    model.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, hooks=train_hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 352, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 809, in _train_model
    input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 668, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 760, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "wide_deep.py", line 187, in train_input_fn
    return input_fn(train_file, flags.epochs_per_eval, True, flags.batch_size)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'epochs_per_eval'
```

I'm new to this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is a mistake in the code. change `epochs_per_eval` to `epochs_between_eval`. It is related to command line argument parsing. Since there is no argument with the name `epochs_per_eval` it is raising an error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they fixed this is the master branch, but has not made it into the latest release yet:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/3777